# Getting a large ugly play button before MP4 video starts in HTML5 App

Tags: css, html, video, ionic-framework, html5-video

We use mp4 videos that are embedded into our app and loaded locally. Before the video starts playing there is a brief flash of an ugly large play button the size of the container.

Is there a way to avoid this or perhaps put a holding image before it plays?

Here is a screenshot of what flashes up for a moment
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qz349.jpg]

My html5 video code is

```
<ion-content padding="true" overflow-scroll="true">
    <div class="video-container" data-tap-disable="true">
    <video id="myVideo" controls="controls" preload="metadata" autoplay="autoplay" webkit-playsinline="webkit-playsinline" class="videoPlayer"><source src="{{product.video}}" type="video/mp4"/></video>
    </div>  
  </ion-content>
```

Answer (score 1):

I have set a background color with !important to the video-container and a background image as the poster poster="img/poster.jpg" to the video selector which I think is the part that has solved this.